# logout password shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, passwords

I have created a shiny app using this code:[password example](https://github.com/treysp/shiny_password)

Everything works fine, but i've got this issue:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$ui <- renderUI({   
        if (user_input$authenticated == FALSE){ 
            fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                      fluidRow(sidebarPanel(column(width = 12, includeMarkdown("./md/intro.md")),
                                            ),
                      mainPanel(column(width = 7, offset = 2,
                                       h1("please login"),
                                       uiOutput("uiLogin"),
                                       uiOutput("pass")
                                       )
                                )
                                )
                      )
          }
          else if (user_input$authenticated == TRUE){
                fileInput(inputId = "datensatz", label = "Datensatz laden"),
                 plotOutput("test6")}
```

This works fine and i can login with several usernames and passwords saved in a seperate file.

Now i added a logout button:

```
observeEvent(input$logout,{
    user_input$authenticated <- FALSE
    })
```

I can logout and the shiny app shows the login-screen. My problem is:

when I click the login button, I can login without username or password. The credentials must be loaded somewhere and I cannot figure out, where.

someone got an idea?

Comment: Presumably the username and password are still stored in variables somewhere and you don't remove them on logout

Comment: yeah. i think this is the issue. but how to remove them? i can restart the whole app with: `closeAllConnections()`, but i dont want to do it this way

Comment: Have you tried re-initialising `user_input` during logout?

Comment: How can I do this

Comment: Just use the same code from when you originally specified the reactive variable.

Comment: doesnt work :(.

Comment: Strange, it should do. You could otherwise try to overwrite the username and password elements. It might be worth adding some debugging lines to see exactly what is being stored when.

Comment: You need to return all these values `user_input <- reactiveValues(authenticated = FALSE, valid_credentials = FALSE, 
                               user_locked_out = FALSE, status = "")` to default values when user logout. I did not read the code carefully but you may need to create ReactiveValues for `row_username` and `row_password` and clear them also on logout.

Comment: I also tried this using it with observeEvent.

Comment: The default is FALSE

Comment: @derlu  create ReactiveValues for `row_username` and `row_password` and clear them also on logout

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks